# Recreating a triangular-ended button shape in CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I’m trying to recreate this shape in CSS3.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/89qIwtf.png]

This was my solution:

```html
<span><div id="shape"></div></span>
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 88px;
}

#shape {
   width: 160px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background: #dcdcdc;
}

#shape:before {
   height: 76px;
   width: 76px;
   top: 20px;
   content:"";
   position: absolute; 
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   left: 60px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);

}

#shape:after {
   height: 76px;
   width: 76px;
   top: 20px;
   content:"";
   position: absolute; 
   border-radius: 10px;
   left: 220px;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn’t scale: [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyfto) (I changed the background-colors to illustrate the way I did it). It is important that it scales vertically.

A JavaScript solution would work too.

Comment: You already have an image of what you want. Why can't you just use that (after cutting the gray background away)? You could use multiple sizes for you page.

Comment: how do you want scale it ??

Comment: Sadly jQuery can't directly set the height of the pseudo elements, or you would be able to set it with jQuery. If you want to add other HTML elements, it would be easy to do with jQuery.

Comment: @TusharGupta *It is important that it scales vertically*

Comment: have you considered using SVG for this rather than trying to achieve it in pure CSS? It would be dead easy to create it and scale it properly as an SVG image.

Comment: @11684 I didn't take an image because I have like 5 different colors and 3 different shape sizes.

Comment: @Spudley I'll give that a shot. Don't know anything about SVG yet, but I just learned that you can manipulate it in JS, so that might work out.

Comment: see this article http://www.queness.com/post/13901/create-beautiful-hexagon-shapes-with-pure-css3

Answer (score 2):

One posibility could be using 3d transforms:

```
.diamond {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 88px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-perspective: 100px;
    -moz-perspective: 100px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

.diamond:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 51%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    transform: rotateX(20deg);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.diamond:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 51%;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/8A2bT/)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

demo http://jsfiddle.net/Le8Hw/2/

style:

```
#kougiland{
    position:relative;
    width:110px;
    height:34px;
    margin:100px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color:red;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #ccc, 10px 5px 8px -4px #ccc, -9px 5px 8px -4px #CCC;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.35) 50%, rgba(225, 225, 225, 0) 51%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0) 100%);
}

#kougiland:before,#kougiland:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top: 4px;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px; 
    background:red;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    background-color:red;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.35) 50%, rgba(225, 225, 225, 0) 51%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0) 100%);
}
#kougiland:before{
    left:-14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 11px -4px #ccc;
}
#kougiland:after{
    right:-14px;
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 11px -4px #ccc;
}
```

**markup:**

```
<div id=kougiland>weiter</div>
```

just change the color as you like and have fun with it :-)

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem... it needs to be able to change height dynamically based on the content.

Comment: then use for speudo el width:100%; and set the height with jquery

Comment: You cannot access pseudo elements with jquery/js. They are created elements and not part of the DOM.

Comment: this solution isn't cross browser.